# Unable to verify if radio button is selected or not and type=radio is not highlighting any element in the application

Tags: selenium, xpath, radio-button

I am unable to check whether the radio button is selected or not  is not highlighting anything in the application. 
i have tried isselected() but it is not giving me the result.

How can i check if radio button is selected? 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCbHj.png)

```
<div _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-group col-md-12 p-0">
    <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check radio p-0">
        <input _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-input" type="radio">
        <label _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-label">All</label>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check radio p-0">
        <input _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-input" type="radio">
        <label _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-label">None</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I guess the screenshot is when the radio button is not selected, So please manually select and then post its html screenshot

Comment: This Radio button is selected by default and the html screenshot is of the same element.  Actually there is not difference between the radio button which is selected and the one which is not selected. I have added new screenshot of both (the radio button selected and the one not selected)

Comment: Please share html in text format, screenshot of app and add language you're using.

Comment: Just to check if it is inside any frame?

Comment: What result do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below codes should give you checked status of radio/checkbox elements (Java):

```
boolean checked = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".form-check-input")).isSelected();
```

or

```
boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".form-check-input")).getAttribute("checked"));

boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-check-input")).getAttribute("checked"));

boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type=radio].form-check-input")).getAttribute("checked"));

boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".form-check.radio.p-0 .form-check-input")).isSelected();
```

If you want to get radio by label "All", you can use xpath below:

```
boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='All']/preceding-sibling::input[1]")).isSelected();
```

Comment: Can you also please explain this? specially the cssSelector part. why(".form-check-input") .

Comment: `.form-check-input` is a class and easiest way to find your element.

Comment: I have the html like this.. to identified the element i am facing dificulties and All is selected by default  which is getting identified by isselected()      <div _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-group col-md-12 p-0">
<div _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check radio p-0">
<input _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-input" type="radio">
<label _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-label">All</label>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check radio p-0">
<input _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-input" type="radio">
<label _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-check-label">None</label>
</div>